# How i can encrypt my localstorage data with Vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web, encryption

I am trying to figure out how I can encrypt my local storage data from users. This is my cart storage in LocalStorage:
[image]

I use the server-side client to display my items in the cart but I don't want this data to be visible to every user so I want to encrypt them but I don't find a way how I can encrypt them with vanilla javascript. If you have any suggestions I will appreciate it, thank you!

Comment: Local storage isn't visible to every user, just the client accessing your site. There's no point in encrypting it.

Comment: interesting, never done it before, but I know that there is a native solution called `Crypto`  , but I can't tell you if is good for this solution, I just know that exist something native, **how to use:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto **more details:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API

Comment: You cannot hide this data from the user. You have to decrypt it eventually to do anything useful with it, at which point it becomes visible. Not to mention to that the encryption key has to be present on the device anyway. You have no real control over what happens on their device. Any information you don't want them to see must not be transmitted to their device (or be encrypted _before_ transmitting it), period.

Comment: @Peter So the solution is to encrypt my data and then to set them to local storage?